# UIInterfaceOrientation cannot determine interface orientation on iOS 7 and iOS 8 iPhones

Tags: ios, objective-c, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation, portrait

I set a function to determine which interface orientation the device is as below.

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        [self layoutPortrait:self.view];
        NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait");
    }
    else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        [self layoutLandscape:self.view];
        NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape");
    }
    else
    {
        [self layoutPortrait:self.view];
        NSLog(@"Unknow Interface Orientation!");
    }
```

I always put my device on a table and the interface orientation is portrait.
However, it prints "UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape" while compiling and it only happens on iOS 7 and iOS 8 iPhones but iPad and any iOS 9 devices.
I don't know how to make it determine the right orientation.

Comment: What About UIDeviceOrientation?

Comment: I've also tried UIDeviceOrientation, but both iOS7 and iOS 8 iPhones printed "UIDeviceOrientationUnknown" and the app still shows in landscape while being launched.

Comment: silly question did you start listening for orientation change notification?

Comment: have you tried checking orientation of status bar `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` yet?

Comment: I tried....it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for io9 as well, try to see if this use case is really required.
Most time i see this is insignificant.

Comment: i am not sure if already a bug exists in apple, i assume difficulty is due to we need additional 'G' sensor both in x and y direction, today i think we have sensor only in one axis. Till fix it is good to have modified use case/UX to get this unnoticed.